# Dockerized application does not find filesystem image

Tags: c#, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have followed these steps:

1) Create a new ASP.NET Core Web application (MVC) without Docker support.

2) Create two new folders (one inside the other) inside the solution called Application\Image (Application is at the same level as the Controllers folder).

3) Add a file called TestImage.png into the Image folder.

4) Access the file successfully using the following code:

```
byte[] image = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("Application\\Image\\TestImage.png");
```

Expected behaviour up to now; here is the problematic bit:

5) Right click on the solution and select: Add Container Orchestration Support/Docker Compose/Linux (target OS)

6) Run the project (docker-compose is the startup project).  I get an error saying: `System.IO.IOException: 'Invalid argument'`

I have done a lot of Googling and it tells me I have to configure the Dockerfile to copy the image to the container.  The Dockerfile currently looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj WebApplication1/
RUN dotnet restore WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/WebApplication1
RUN dotnet build WebApplication1.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish WebApplication1.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApplication1.dll"]
```

I have tried adding this line (below this line: `COPY WebApplication1/WebApplication1.csproj WebApplication1/`):

```
COPY WebApplication1/Application/Image/TestImage.png WebApplication1/Application/Image/
```

However, I see the same error.  How can I get the app to read the image now I am using Docker?